# Split a string every second occurence of a delimiter with regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I would need your help on this, as I'm not very good at regex expressions!

I want to split the following string at every second occurrence of "/"

```
Alien 3 / Argentina / Alien 3 / Brazil / Alien 3 / Croatia / Vetřelec 3 / Czech Republic / Vetřelec 3 / Czechoslovakia / Alien³ / Denmark / Tulnukas 3 / Estonia / Alien³ / France / Alien 3 / Germany / Άλιεν³: Η Τελική Αναμέτρηση / Greece / A végső megoldás: Halál / Hungary / Alien³ / Italy / Svešais³ / Latvia / Svetimas 3 / Lithuania / Alien³ / Mexico / Alien 3 / Peru / Obcy 3 / Poland / Alien 3 - A Desforra / Portugal / Alien 3 / Romania / Чужой 3 / Russia / Туђин 3 / Serbia / Votrelec 3 / Slovakia / Osmi potnik 3 / Slovenia / Alien³ / Spain / 異形3 / Taiwan / Чужий 3 / Ukraine / Alien³ / UK / Alien³ / USA / Alien 3 / Uruguay
```

Ending up to an array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Amelie / Argentina [1] => Amelie / Australia [2] => O Fabuloso Destino de Amélie Poulain / Brazil [3] => El fabuloso destino de Amelie Poulain / Chile [4] => Amelie / Croatia [5] => Amélie z Montmartru / Czech Republic [6] => Den fabelagtige Amélie fra Montmartre / Denmark [7] => Amélie / Finland [8] => Le Fabuleux Destin d'Amélie Poulain / France [9] => Die fabelhafte Welt der Amelie / Germany [10] => Αμελί / Greece [11] => Amélie csodálatos élete / Hungary [12] => Il favoloso mondo di Amélie / Italy [13] => Ameri / Japan [14] => Amelija iš Monmartro / Lithuania [15] => Amelie / Mexico [16] => Den fabelaktige Amélie fra Montmartre / Norway [17] => Amelie / Peru [18] => Amelia / Poland [19] => O Fabuloso Destino de Amélie / Portugal [20] => Amélie / Romania [21] => Амели / Russia [22] => Чудесна судбина Амелије Пулен / Serbia [23] => Amélia / Slovakia [24] => Amelie / Spain [25] => Amelie från Montmartre / Sweden [26] => 艾蜜莉的異想世界 / Taiwan [27] => Амелі / Ukraine [28] => Amélie / UK [29] => Amélie / USA [30] => Ameli / Uzbekistan [31] => Amélie / World-wide )
```

What I ended up to is simply

```
/(.* \/ .*) /
```

, which doesn't do what I want as it leaves the last pair out of the array because of that whitespace at the end of the pattern as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/QZIPE1/1)...

Please don't propose other solutions with explode's and the implode's every other chunk. It has to be done with regex. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` for this. So if your input string is `$str`, the `$result` can be achieved as follows:

```php
$count = preg_match_all("~[^/]+/[^/]+~", $str, $result);
```

Comment: Indeed $result[0] holds the array I wanted! It's still puzzling me how this works, but with the pattern explanation of regex101.com I'll get a hold of it! Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Of course! It all makes perfect sense now! Your pattern fetches only one result, and preg_match_all takes care of bringing all those _single_ results... Very clever approach, and a super simple pattern... Thanks a lot once again!